# making np.where returning the same coordinate if the same value comes multiple time

Tags: python, numpy

as the title say, I want to make np.where() returning a coordinate multiple time if it comes across the same value, exemple:

```
import numpy as np
a = 2*np.arange(5)
b = [8,8]
condition = np.isin(a,b)
print np.where(condition)
>>> (array([4], dtype=int64),)
```

it returns [4] because a[4] = 8, but since b has two 8, I want it to returns [4,4], is there a way to do this without iterating throught each b value?

Comment: What if you have some values in `b` that don't exist in `a` or exist in `a` but duplicated in `a`?

Comment: if no value in `b` are in `a` , it returns no coordinates (the output of np.where() are coordinates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your `a`,`b`:

```
In [687]: condition=isin(a,b)
In [688]: condition
Out[688]: array([False, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

`where` just tells us the index of that one `True` value.

Switch the test, and you find that both items of `b` are in `a`.

```
In [697]: isin(b,a)
Out[697]: array([ True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

You could use a simple broadcasted comparison:

```
In [700]: a[:,None]==b
Out[700]: 
array([[False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)
In [701]: np.where(a[:,None]==b)
Out[701]: (array([4, 4], dtype=int32), array([0, 1], dtype=int32))
```

`isin` (and `in1d` which it uses) worries about uniqueness, but you aren't.  So testing the array `==` gives you more control.

test if both values in `b` match the same `a` element

```
In [703]: (a[:,None]==b).all(axis=1)
Out[703]: array([False, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

test if any - essentially what `in1d` does:

```
In [704]: (a[:,None]==b).any(axis=1)
Out[704]: array([False, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: `a[:,None]` makes `a` 2d, (n,1).  The usual broadcasting rules apply if `a` is already 2d.  It might be easier to understand the broadcasting with a `+` or `*` operation.  You many also want to use `any` or `all` to reduce one dimension or other.

Comment: where would I use any() or all()? sorry if this sounds dumb, I am new to working with numpy

Comment: examples added.